# Chapter on PDF pages landscape page incorrectly orientated

Tags: pdfpages

I'm importing a single page using the `\includepdf` command with the following paramaters:

```
\includepdf[pages=1,pagecommand={\chapter{ChapterTitle}},landscape}{filename.pdf}
```

This works and I am getting a chapter title rendered onto the imported page, however it is on its side (Imagine the originally portrait page has been tipped on its side so the top is to the right). Is there a way to fix the orientation of this chapter text?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: don't use landscape, that's the wrong option, use angle.

Comment: That doesn't work Ulrike as the resulting page is portrait, but the content I'm displaying on it is landscape. It's a diagram which I would like to have the chapter text overlayed on the top right corner of.

Edit for clarity: the page itself is portrait, but the imported content displayed on the page is rotated.

Comment: landscape is the wrong option. If you want more help: make a complete example. The mwe package contains various example-pdf that you can use instead of your filename.pdf.